# Agora.io UE4 Blueprint connected more than two people

Tags: agora.io

Good afternoon. I am using Agora - UE4 Bluprint version. 
I can not find a way to access the frame of the new connected user. This is provided that more than two people are connected. The first connected each tick causes "OnLocalFrameReceivedDelegate" 
all subsequent connected call "OnRemoteFrameReceivedDelegate". In total, it turns out that you can broadcast the image from the camera of the first connected or the second. And how to take the camera of all subsequent connected?

Answer (score 0):

In our blueprint example, we have two images that receive Agora video frames:

CameraFrame - the Local user

InterlocutorFrame - the Remote user

If you call into the blueprint example with 3 or more people, you will see that you can switch between UIDs in the dropdown menu.
[image: Change UID From DropDown]

Switching UIDs changes the InterlocutorFrame video feed to the remote user whose UID matches the one you specify, like so:
[image: Get Remote User Video Frames]

To display multiple users, you need to place multiple UI Images on the screen, and `SetBrushFromTexture` with the appropriate UID.

I would suggest using the `OnUserJoined` callback to create a new image actor, and store the new incoming UID inside that actor. You could also store all the current UIDs in one place, or use another solution that you think is best :)